9 people pass candies in a circle. find number of unique sequences of candies number.
Nine people stand along a circle facing the center, numbered $1, 2, \ldots, 9$. The $i$-th person initially holds $i$ candies. Each person gives some candies (can be $0$) to the person standing in the right hand at the same time (for example, person $1$ gives $1$ candy to person $2$, person $2$ gives $0$ candy to person $3, \ldots, 9$ gives $5$ candies to person $1$), they cannot give a bigger number of candies they hold on their hands. We define the sequence of candy numbers as the number of candies held by the 1st to the 9th person, so the initial sequence is $(1, 2, \ldots, 9)$. After they give candies, how many possible unique sequences of candy numbers can we get? Will the answer be different if now they pass candies to the person on the left instead?
I am thinking that for each person $i$, let $g_i$​ represent the number of candies given by person $i$ to person $i + 1$. The sequence resulting is $( 1 + g_9 , 2 + g_1 , 3 + g_2 , \ldots , 9 + g_8)$. How can I proceed from here?

Note that the total number of candies does not change.

You forgot to subtract the given candies in the resulting sequence. Eg person 2 ends up with 2 - g2 + g1.

Hint: 2 ways are equivalent iff everyone can give 1 more or 1 less candy. Use this to set up an equivalence relation on $ 0 \leq s_i \leq i$ and found the number of unique entries.

The situation depicted raises suspicions on the nature of the "candies"
